# "Save and copy profile to all stack exchange accounts" does not appear

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-sync

`Save and copy profile to all stack exchange accounts` button does not only ["vanish"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113910/copy-profile-to-all-stack-exchange-network-accounts-button-vanishes) but does not appear at all for me on Stack Overflow.

I came to know about the very existence of this button only on Super User.

Can you please make it appear here on Stack Overflow, too?

Comment: It *should* be showing up for you. It does show up for me, and always has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you had two profiles hanging around for some reason? (Anna had to fix up a question of yours on Super User as well, since it was posted from the wrong account)

If you were logged in as a user who didn't have any other accounts, this would kinda make sense: that button only shows up when there are other, associated accounts on the network.

Comment: ah, ok, now it makes sense to me, thx.